# how to draw captcha image from other web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, streamreader

i have one important project. i have to draw dynamically captcha image from running other web site captcha. here i have to made one web request to other login page. and draw captcha same as displayed other web site. here i have to set this captcha image src to my asp image control and user can entry it after that login success.

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-Filing/UserLogin/LoginHome.html");

            //var postData = "User ID=BEPPG5845B";
            //postData += "&password=shalsoft$7008";
            //postData += "&dob=21/09/1991";
            //var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            //request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            //using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            //{
                //stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            //}

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = (dynamic)null ;

            using (responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd())
            {
                responseString = Regex.Replace(responseString, @"\s+", string.Empty);
                responseString = ((String)responseString).Replace("\"", "'");
                if (responseString != null)
                {

                    int captha = ((String)responseString).IndexOf("<img id='captchaImg'");
                    if (captha != -1)
                    {
                       responseString = ((String)responseString).Remove(0, captha + 19);
                       int src = ((String)responseString).IndexOf("src");
                       if (src != -1)
                       {
                           responseString = ((String)responseString).Remove(0, src + 5); 
                           int dot = ((String)responseString).IndexOf(".png");
                           if(dot != -1)
                           {
                               Image1.ImageUrl = ((String)responseString).Substring(0, dot + 4);
                           }
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here it's giving me error like this:

```
Server Error in '/PAN' Application.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IDisposable'
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IDisposable'

Source Error:


Line 35:             var responseString = (dynamic)null ;
Line 36: 
Line 37:             using (responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd())
Line 38:             {
Line 39:                 responseString = Regex.Replace(responseString, @"\s+", string.Empty);


Source File: c:\Users\SHALIN\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\PAN\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 37

Stack Trace:


[RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IDisposable']
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) +139
   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(CallSite site, T0 arg0) +438
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\SHALIN\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\PAN\Default.aspx.cs:37
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: Have you read the error message?

Comment: The included source code and the error is too different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The included source code and the error is too different things.

However, the error is a cast error, the correct way to convert a stream to a string is like this:

```
string responseString = null;
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
{
    responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // ...
}
```